# Osmdroid how to move position marker in animative way with animateTo function

Tags: android, osmdroid, osrm, osmbonuspack

Im doing car navigation app based on Osmdroid and selfhosted OSRM and Nominatim.
What im trying to archive right now is simply smooth position marker and map movement while driving. Second is simple, using  animateTo function of osmBonudPack. First one, i dont see any function to move marker in animative way in osmbonuspack  so ive created my own handler to animate marker but now map and marker are not synchronized. Is there any dedicated function ?